# Moxy List<Map<String,String>> not expected marshalling

Tags: eclipselink, marshalling, moxy

I'm trying to marshal this class:

```
package otherTest;

import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

public class SearchResult {


    private List<Map<String,String>> listOfMap;

    private Map<String,Collection<String>> mapWithList;


    public List<Map<String, String>> getListOfMap() {
        return listOfMap;
    }

    public void setListOfMap(List<Map<String, String>> listOfMap) {
        this.listOfMap = listOfMap;
    }

    public Map<String, Collection<String>> getMapWithList() {
        return mapWithList;
    }

    public void setMapWithList(Map<String, Collection<String>> mapWithList) {
        this.mapWithList = mapWithList;
    }
    public SearchResult(){}

}
```

oxm.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xml-bindings 
    xmlns="http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/xsds/persistence/oxm"
    package-name="otherTest" 
    xml-mapping-metadata-complete="true">
    <java-types>
        <java-type name="SearchResult">
            <xml-root-element/>
            <java-attributes>
                <xml-element java-attribute="listOfMap"/>
                <xml-element java-attribute="mapWithList"/>
            </java-attributes>
        </java-type>
    </java-types>
</xml-bindings>
```

Demo.java

```
package otherTest;

import java.io.InputStream;
import java.util.*;

import javax.xml.bind.*;
import org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.JAXBContextProperties;

public class Demo {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Map<String, Object> properties = new HashMap<String , Object>();
        ClassLoader classLoader = Demo.class.getClassLoader();
        InputStream modelStream = classLoader.getResourceAsStream("otherTest/oxm.xml");
        properties.put(JAXBContextProperties.OXM_METADATA_SOURCE, modelStream);
        JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance(new Class[] {SearchResult.class}, properties);

        List<Map<String,String>> results = new ArrayList<Map<String,String>>();
        Map<String,String> test = new HashMap<String,String>();

        Map<String,Collection<String>> daMashalare = new HashMap<String,Collection<String>>();


        test.put("id","10");
        test.put("publicationTitle","20");
        test.put("paginazione","boh");
        test.put("pageSize", "10");
        results.add(test);

        Collection<String> listaString = new ArrayList<String>();
        listaString.add("testlist");
        daMashalare.put("nothing",listaString);

        SearchResult result = new SearchResult();
        result.setListOfMap(results);
        result.setMapWithList(daMashalare);

        Marshaller marshaller = jc.createMarshaller();
        marshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, true);
        marshaller.marshal(result, System.out);
    }

}
```

Unluckly the output that I get is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<searchResult>
   <listOfMap>{id=10, paginazione=boh, pageSize=10, publicationTitle=20}</listOfMap>
   <mapWithList>
      <entry>
         <key>nothing</key>
         <value>testlist</value>
      </entry>
   </mapWithList>
</searchResult>
```

So As you can see the listOfMap attribute is not how I would like to see it

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<searchResult>
   <listOfMap>
      <id>10</id>
      <paginazione>boh</paginazione>
      <pageSize>10</pageSize>
      <publicationTitle>20</publicationTitle>
   </listOfMap>
   <mapWithList>
      <entry>
         <key>nothing</key>
         <value>testlist</value>
      </entry>
   </mapWithList>
</searchResult>
```

How Can I set an adapter to solve this problem? I have also included this test package:
that you can download and test it http://bit.ly/14aWIu1

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a generic solution for Map:
**`MapAdapter<K,V>`**

```
    package otherTest;    
    import java.util.HashMap;
    import java.util.Map;
    import javax.xml.bind.annotation.adapters.XmlAdapter;

    public class MapAdapter<K, V> extends XmlAdapter<MapType<K, V>, Map<K, V>> {

        @Override
        public Map<K, V> unmarshal(MapType<K, V> v) throws Exception {
            HashMap<K, V> map = new HashMap<K, V>();

            for (MapEntryType<K, V> mapEntryType : v.getEntry()) {
                map.put(mapEntryType.getKey(), mapEntryType.getValue());
            }
            return map;
        }

        @Override
        public MapType marshal(Map<K, V> v) throws Exception {
            MapType<K, V> mapType = new MapType<K, V>();

            for (Map.Entry<K, V> entry : v.entrySet()) {
                MapEntryType<K, V> mapEntryType = new MapEntryType<K, V>();
                mapEntryType.setKey(entry.getKey());
                mapEntryType.setValue(entry.getValue());
                mapType.getEntry().add(mapEntryType);
            }
            return mapType;
        }
    }
```

**`MapEntryType<K,V>`**

```
    package otherTest;

    import java.util.Map;
    import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessType;
    import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessorType;
    import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement;


    @XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.PROPERTY)
    public class MapEntryType<K, V> {

        private K key;
        private V value;

        public MapEntryType() {
        }

        public MapEntryType(Map.Entry<K, V> e) {
            key = e.getKey();
            value = e.getValue();
        }

        @XmlElement
        public K getKey() {
            return key;
        }

        public void setKey(K key) {
            this.key = key;
        }

        @XmlElement
        public V getValue() {
            return value;
        }

        public void setValue(V value) {
            this.value = value;
        }
    }
```

**`MapType<K,V>`**

```
    package otherTest;

    import java.util.ArrayList;
    import java.util.List;
    import java.util.Map;


    public class MapType<K, V> {

        private List<MapEntryType<K, V>> entry = new ArrayList<MapEntryType<K, V>>();

        public MapType() {
        }

        public MapType(Map<K, V> map) {
            for (Map.Entry<K, V> e : map.entrySet()) {
                entry.add(new MapEntryType<K, V>(e));
            }
        }

        public List<MapEntryType<K, V>> getEntry() {
            return entry;
        }

        public void setEntry(List<MapEntryType<K, V>> entry) {
            this.entry = entry;
        }
    }
```

**SearchResult**

```
    package otherTest;

    import java.util.Collection;
    import java.util.List;
    import java.util.Map;

    import javax.xml.bind.annotation.adapters.XmlJavaTypeAdapter;

    public class SearchResult {


        private List<Map<String,String>> listOfMap;

        private Map<String,Collection<String>> mapWithList;

        @XmlJavaTypeAdapter(MapAdapter.class)
        public List<Map<String, String>> getListOfMap() {
            return listOfMap;
        }

        public void setListOfMap(List<Map<String, String>> listOfMap) {
            this.listOfMap = listOfMap;
        }

        public Map<String, Collection<String>> getMapWithList() {
            return mapWithList;
        }

        public void setMapWithList(Map<String, Collection<String>> mapWithList) {
            this.mapWithList = mapWithList;
        }
        public SearchResult(){}

    }
```

**Test**

```
    package otherTest;

    import java.io.InputStream;

    import java.util.ArrayList;
    import java.util.HashMap;
    import java.util.List;
    import java.util.Map;

    import javax.xml.transform.TransformerException;
    import javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext;
    import javax.xml.bind.JAXBException;
    import javax.xml.bind.Marshaller;

    import org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.JAXBContextProperties;


        public class Test {

            public static void main(String[] args) throws TransformerException, Exception {

                Map<String, Object> properties = new HashMap<String, Object>();
                Marshaller marshaller = null;
                ClassLoader classLoader = Test.class.getClassLoader();

                List<Map<String,String>> results = new ArrayList<Map<String,String>>();
                Map<String,String> test = new HashMap<String,String>();
                test.put("id","10");
                test.put("publicationTitle","20");
                test.put("paginazione","boh");
                test.put("pageSize", "10");
                results.add(test);

                InputStream modelStream = classLoader.getResourceAsStream("test/oxm.xml");
                JAXBContext ctx = null;
                properties.put(JAXBContextProperties.OXM_METADATA_SOURCE, modelStream );
                try {
                    ctx = JAXBContext.newInstance(new Class[] {SearchResult.class}, properties);
                } catch (JAXBException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                marshaller = ctx.createMarshaller();
                marshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, true);
                SearchResult result = new SearchResult();
                result.setListOfMap(results);
                marshaller.marshal(result, System.out);

            }

        }
```

**Output**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<listOfMap>
   <entry>
      <key xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:type="xsd:string">id</key>
      <value xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:type="xsd:string">10</value>
   </entry>
   <entry>
      <key xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:type="xsd:string">paginazione</key>
      <value xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:type="xsd:string">boh</value>
   </entry>
   <entry>
      <key xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:type="xsd:string">pageSize</key>
      <value xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:type="xsd:string">10</value>
   </entry>
   <entry>
      <key xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:type="xsd:string">publicationTitle</key>
      <value xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:type="xsd:string">20</value>
   </entry>
</listOfMap>
```